# Looking for another way to say 'someone is incompetent of carrying out an assignment"

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Have you heard of the Peter principle?

> In an organizational structure, assessing an employee's potential for a promotion is often based on their performance in their current job. This can eventually result in their being promoted beyond their highest level of competence and potentially then to a role in which they are not competent, referred to as their "level of incompetence"

I want to know is there a word for the "act of occupying a position that you are incompetent in"?

Comment: i wish there were a neologism ... like 'mr x has been petered'!

Comment: Perhaps 'lifer' would convey the meaning someone will never rise any higher ... because they've already reached a level where they are incompetent. Yoy could at least feel confident others would interpret that as being very insulting. :)

Answer (score 1):

["Unfit"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfit) is both technically correct, and generally understood.

Usage can fall into the forms of:

- Unfit *noun*: "Unfit mother", "Unfit leader"
- Unfit for ____ : "Unfit for motherhood", "Unfit for leadership"
- Unfit to _____ : "Unfit to Parent", "Unfit to lead"

Comment: but "unfit" still describes the person, I want to talk about the act.
like: This position has been occupied by an unfit person and .......
Tnx for the time